# Angular-meteor user collection only returns 1 object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, meteor

I am writing an app with angular as front end and meteor as back end and I want to retrieve every user in the collection "Users" (added module accounts-ui and accounts-password). But when I execute the following code, it only returns one object (the last added) while there are 3 users.

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
angular.module('timeAppApp')
.controller('SignInCtrl', function($scope, $meteor, $location) {

    $scope.LogIn = function() {
        console.log($meteor.collection(Meteor.users).subscribe('users_by_email', $scope.username));
        console.log($meteor.collection(Meteor.users).subscribe('all_users'));
    };

});

}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    // Returns all users find by email
    Meteor.publish('users_by_email', function(emailE){
        return Meteor.users.find({'emails.address': emailE});
    });

Meteor.publish('all_users', function(){
    return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {emails: 1}});
})
```

I'm new to meteor so I'm still experimenting but now I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, 
On server side

```
Meteor.methods({
     get_users_by_email: function (emailE) {
         return Meteor.users.find({ emails: { $elemMatch: { address: emailE } } }).fetch();
    }
});
```

On client side

```
$meteor.call('get_users_by_email', $scope.username).then(
            function(data){
                console.log('success get_users_by_email', data);
            },
            function(err){
                console.log('failed', err);
            }

        );
```

Comment: I already tried that, but that doesn't work. Is it possible that I implement meteor in my angular wrong?

Comment: when I execute this code 'console.log($meteor.collection(Meteor.users));', the output is the same as the two other console.log()

Comment: when you add this console.log("username == "+ $scope.username); what output do you get?

Comment: the value of the input field with ng-model="username", no errors there. I'm familiar with Angular, but not with Meteor and the integration of Meteor with Angular...

Comment: Try the code above using meteor method calls, I just edited my answer!

Comment: I wish I found that post a few hours back :p Works like a charm!